# How to use subprocess module to execute a .pyc file with argument?

Tags: python, subprocess, pyc

I need to use a module (SigOpt) which runs on python 2.7 while I have an unknown function provided in a .pyc file which runs on python 2.6. So, I need to execute this function with a float argument and return its output into my script.

```
def evaluate_model(y):
    return subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/python <location>/black_box_function.pyc", "y"])
```

Should this work?

Comment: not with 1 argument made of 2 arguments it doesn't. Try `["/usr/bin/python","<location>/black_box_function.pyc", "y"]`

Comment: Why don't you try? Also, fix `"y"` part - you clearly mean to pass variable `y`, not constant string `"y"`